# Facebook album dowloader for Firefox 3.6.17

Tags: facebook, firefox-3.6

I want some addon or software to download facebook albums at one go in Firefox 3.6.17. Previously i was using PhotoJacker but it is not working with Firefox 3.6.17. And most software donot work with the latest version of Firefox.

Why is this.? Any other workaround than downgrading Firefox.?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why is this?**

> Facebook has sent me a Cease & Desist
>   notice (click here to view) stating
>   that PhotoJacker/FacePAD violates
>   Section 3.2 of their Statement of
>   Rights and Responsibilities:
>
> *You will not collect users’ content or
>   information, or otherwise access
>   Facebook, using automated means (such
>   as harvesting bots, robots, spiders,
>   or scrapers) without our permission.
>   (Section 3.2)*
>
> PhotoJacker/FacePAD, is in some way, a
>   scraper, since it allows the end-user
>   to download photos (that the user can
>   manually download by right-clicking on
>   the photo and pushing saved
>   target/image as…) from Facebook to
>   their computer in an expeditious
>   manner. For the record, scraping is a
>   very loosely defined term, and not all
>   definitions I’ve read make it sound
>   like PhotoJacker/FacePAD is a scraper.
>
> [...]
>
> Regardless, I am currently a full time
>   student, and I really don’t have the
>   time to deal with this problem.
>   Therefore, I have decided to comply
>   with Facebook’s takedown notice. The
>   program has been removed from Mozilla,
>   and therefore, it can no longer be
>   accessed or downloaded.

Source: [PhotoJacker - Cease & Desist / Facebook Takedown Notice](http://www.photojacker.com/post/2960957283/photojacker-shutdown)

**Any other workaround?**

Well, downgrading is an option if you still have the plugin lying around. Otherwise I don't think that you will find plugins that are still working. I guess facebook contacted all the creators of such plugins to prevent them from beeing available and working.

Another solution could be installing a second firefox (the one with the plugin when it was still working). Assuming you don't have to download whole albums every day or so, this should be manageable.